# Json com relacionamento ManyToMany - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Criei um relacionamento entre minhas tabelas usando `ManyToMany` e atualmente preciso retornar um Json com as informações, porém minhas tabelas encontran-se desta maneira;

```
// 1. Produtos
+-------------+
| id          |
| name        |
| description |
| image       |
|_____________|
// 2. Variações
+-------------+
| id          |
| SKU         |
|_____________|
// 3. Produtos_variacoes
+-------------+
| prod_id     |
| variation_id|
|_____________|
```

1 - A tabela `Produtos` armazena informações gerais dos produtos.

2 - A tabela `Variações` armazena os códigos que o produto possui

3 - A tabela `produtos_variações` serve de "pivô" para armazenar o `id` do produto e o `id` da variação.

Quando vou retornar um Json entre 2 tabelas eu faço seguinte maneira;

```
$dados = Product::with('Variacoes')->get();
return Response::json($dados);
```

Porém eu preciso relacionar a tabela `produtos_variações` para poder saber qual produto possui qual variação.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Comment: Como o JSON está sendo retornado hoje?

Comment: se eu usar o exemplo que mostrei no post esta retornando uma lista de produtos com uma lista de variações, porém estas tabelas não possuem relacionamento entre sí.

Comment: Isso é retornado no campo `pivot` do seu json

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara. Porque precisa relacionar `produtos_variacoes`? Por acaso ela não já está relacionada? Você configurou corretamente seu `belongsToMany`?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente por convenção do Laravel, o nome da sua tabela many to many deve ser no singular e em ordem alfabética. Renomeie sua tabela para `produto_variacao`

No seu model Produto (nome da tabela: produtos)

```
public function variacoes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Variacao');
}
```

No seu model Variacao (nome da tabela: variacoes)

```
public function produtos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Produto');
}
```

Na primeira significa que um Produto pertence a muitas variações.

Na segunda significa que uma Variacao pertence a muitos produtos.

No seu controller:

```
public function index() {
    $a = App\Produto::find(1)->variacoes; // retorna todas as variações do produto com id 1.
    $b = App\Variacao::find(1)->produtos; // retorna todos os produtos da variação com id 1.
    $c = App\Produto::with('variacoes')->get(); // retorna os produtos as variações embutidas.

    return response()->json($a);
}
```

Teste os 3, um deles irá resolver seus problemas. Eu recomendo instalar a extenção Postman do Chrome para testar o retorno dos JSON's. Não se esqueça de configurar o arquivo de rotas corretamente também.